# Small circuit explanation

Tags: resistors, voltage-measurement

I apologize that this is really simple for specialists, but since I am not one, I would like some assistance in this regard.
What is the electrical condition of the resistors, please? They operate either in parallel or in series. What may my analog input's maximum voltage be? I intended to compute it, but it's hard for me to understand what's happening. If someone can help me, I would be grateful. [image]

Comment: Welcome! I’ve taken the liberty to rename your title from short circuit to small circuit since it does not appear to be anything related to a short circuit.

Comment: What are `AI1` and `SAI1/2.6A` connections? Where are they going to or coming from? Can you put the full schematic or at least the relevant sections? Judging from the directional port symbols, I assume both of them are incoming (input) signals to the circuit shown (e.g. `AI1` signal comes to the circuit, not goes from circuit).

Comment: which terminal is the input, which is the output? roiughly what voltages are expected at the input. As a first step I suggest you answer these questions, then maybe draw the circuit with input at left, output at right and ground at the bottom. Just doing this should already help you to answer your own question.

Comment: The SAI1 stays clamped at 2.5V in case A11 voltage is more then 35V.

Comment: These resistors are neither in series nor parallel.

Comment: @Hearth, They are not in parallel but why not in series?

Comment: @Circuitfantasist Because of the presence of D33, C1, and whatever's attached to global label SAI1/2.6A.

Comment: @Hearth, Agree... only when these additional devices are active and shunt the resistors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Understanding the "small circuit"

This is a typical life situation when something unknown stands in front of us and we need to understand what it is, what it is for and how it works. In addition to this, it is poorly drawn, rotated, poorly written with specific multi-digit values... In a word, it is a circuit diagram for doing and not for understanding. So we have to do something to make it easier to understand.

The first thing we can try is to rotate the schematic 90 degrees counter-clockwise (to leave the ground underneath) and try to recognize some functional circuit building blocks.

So for example, we see three resistors connected in series. This resembles a *voltage divider* with two outputs. Its lower output is grounded and shunted with a capacitor. Ah, in addition to the voltage reduction, there is also *filtering*.

Then we see that the upper divider's output is also shunted but now by a Zener diode. Sure, it looks like a *diode clamp*. What could be the purpose?  Obviously to limit the input voltage to a safe value.

## Building the "small circuit"

Let's now sort out these jumbled thoughts a bit by trying to build the circuit in a logical order.

### Reducing the input voltage

First we need to reduce the input voltage (14 times, for some reason unknown to us). To do this, we assemble a voltage divider with two resistors R1 and R2. Then we simulate the circuit using CircuitLab. We use a more specific (CSV) voltage source because we will add "noise" later. This requires us to use a *time-domain simulation* (*DC sweep simulation* does not allow it).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvpaQb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We deliberately set a significantly higher voltage of 100 V and we see on the graph that 7 V is established at the output.

[image: STEP 1]

### Filtering the noise

Now let's connect a bypass capacitor to R2 and insert an AC  "noise" voltage source in series to the input (10 V) DC voltage source. The AC amplitude is significant (1 V) to see the "noise".

**Below the cutoff frequency:** In this case, the capacitor does not shunt the divider's output...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fF20c0.png)</sup>

... and the 100 Hz "noise" appears at the output.

[image: STEP 2_1]

**Above the cutoff frequency:** Now the capacitor shunts the divider's output...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flnjyF.png)</sup>

... and the 10 kHz "noise" does not appear at the output.

[image: STEP 2_2]

### Limiting the output voltage

Finally, we have to somehow protect the analog input. We decide to "clamp" the input voltage by a Zener diode. Only we must not connect it directly to the input but through another resistor. So we split R1 into two resistors and connect the diode clamp to the midpoint. Since there is not such 7.5 V Zener diode in the CircuitLab library, we can replace it by a forward-biased "ideal" diode Z with such a voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl1yPb.png)</sup>

We use again a higher (100 V) input voltage to see the 2.5 V clamped output voltage.

[image: STEP 4]

Comment: Why the nonstandard ("backwards") symbol for a Zener in final circuit?

Comment: @Daniel Chisholm, Thanks for the upvote. I didn't find a 7.5V Zener diode in the CircuitLab library.

Comment: Clamping to 2.5 or 7.5 V? Is it a 2.5 or a 7.5 V Zener diode?

Comment: @Uwe, When Vin reaches 35 V, the "Zener diode" Z fixes the R1-R2 midpoint to 7.5 V. Accordingly, Vout is fixed to 2.5 V. In other words, 7.5 V is a constant input voltage of the voltage divider R2-R3; so a constant 2.5 V voltage appears at its output.

Comment: Hi and thanks a lot. I am very proud of our society to care and share their knowledge to help.

Answer (score 5):

Before D33 conducts (and ignoring the capacitor, which is only a factor when the voltage is changing quickly) the circuit is a simple voltage divider.

Output voltage is input voltage * 7.5k/(7.5k+15k+82k) = input voltage/13.93.

When D33 is conducting, the output voltage is clamped at a nominal 7.5V* 7.5k/(7.5k+15k) = 2.50V.

The input voltage at the point where it clamps will thus be 2.50V*13.93 = 34.8V.

The capacitor forms a low-pass filter with a cutoff frequency of 1/(2*pi*R*C) where C = 10nF and R = 7.5k||(15k+82k) or about 2.3kHz.

This is an ideal behavior, in practice the Zener diode has a curve over which it clamps so the 13.93 ratio won't be very accurate as you approach the 35V input. The designer has used a relatively high voltage Zener which has a sharper "knee" rather than trying to clamp with something like a 2.4V Zener, which is much worse.

Here is a SPICE simulation of the behavior at low frequencies:

[image]

Here is the AC analysis, showing a cutoff frequency as predicted:

[image]

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, I just wonder how you can devote so much attention to such a boring passive circuit:-)

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I am playing with some new software, so it's more tuition than drudgery.

Comment: Spehro Pefhany, Another way to make "small" circuits less boring is to build them :-)

Comment: I am about to cry, I really did not expect that. Thank you so much.